# Python Timer remaining time

Tags: python, timer

How do I calculate the remaining time from the Python Timer object.

```
timer = Timer(10, print, ("expiry"))
timer.start()
...
```

from here, how do I find out what is the remaining time before the timer expired?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just set a value when you start the thread Timer

```
timer = Timer(10, print, ("expiry"))
....
start_time = time.time()
timer.start()
time.sleep(3)
....
print ("Running for : %s seconds"%(time.time()-start_time))
```

You could always make your own timer class

```
class MyTimer(threading._Timer):
    started_at = None
    def start(self):
        self.started_at = time.time()
        threading._Timer.start(self)
    def elapsed(self):
        return time.time() - self.started_at
    def remaining(self):
        return self.interval - self.elapsed()


timer = MyTimer(10, print, ("expiry"))
timer.start()

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    print (timer.remaining())
```

Comment: This works.  I was hoping there is a property in the Timer that I can use without the need of saving the start time myself.

Comment: why are you subclassing from _Timer and not from Timer? Is this a pythonic thing, or is Timer not subclassable or something?